# Straightforward solution on how to stereo calibration and rectifications OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I have been digging on this topic for almost a week and couldn't find any solid solution yet.
It is interesting that no one ever posted a **straightforward** solution on how to calibrate and rectify a stereo camera with OpenCV in order to compute the depth, from here and there([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222763/stereo-calibration-opencv-python-and-disparity-map) for calibration and [this](http://vgg.fiit.stuba.sk/2015-02/2783/) for rectification, the codes posted are not quite integrated though) I have come up with the following code snap, BUT it does not rectify the image OK!!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = {} # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = {} # 2d points in image plane.

# calibrate stereo
for side in ['left', 'right']:
    counter = 0
    images = glob.glob('images/%s*.jpg' %side)
    objpoints[side] = [];
    imgpoints[side] = [];
    for fname in images:
        img = cv2.imread(fname)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Find the chess board corners
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6),None)
        # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
        if ret == True:
            objpoints[side].append(objp)

            cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
            imgpoints[side].append(corners)
            counter += 1

    assert counter == len(images), "missed chessboard!!"


stereocalib_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 100, 1e-5)
stereocalib_flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO | cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST | cv2.CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH | cv2.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL | cv2.CALIB_FIX_K3 | cv2.CALIB_FIX_K4 | cv2.CALIB_FIX_K5
retval,cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpoints['left'], imgpoints['left'], imgpoints['right'], (640, 480), criteria = stereocalib_criteria, flags = stereocalib_flags)

rectify_scale = 0.1 # 0=full crop, 1=no crop
R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, roi1, roi2 = cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, (640, 480), R, T, alpha = rectify_scale)

left_maps = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1, (640, 480), cv2.CV_16SC2)
right_maps = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R2, P2, (640, 480), cv2.CV_16SC2)

# Assuming you have left01.jpg and right01.jpg that you want to rectify
lFrame = cv2.imread('images/left01.jpg')
rFrame = cv2.imread('images/right01.jpg')

left_img_remap = cv2.remap(lFrame, left_maps[0], left_maps[1], cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
right_img_remap = cv2.remap(rFrame, right_maps[0], right_maps[1], cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

for line in range(0, int(right_img_remap.shape[0] / 20)):
    left_img_remap[line * 20, :] = (0, 0, 255)
    right_img_remap[line * 20, :] = (0, 0, 255)

cv2.imshow('winname', np.hstack([left_img_remap, right_img_remap]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
exit(0)
```

The output of the above is the image below
[image]

As you can see the images are not rectified!!

#### Question:

- What is wrong with the code?

Comment: was the chessboard completely visible in both input images?

Comment: probably your chessboard should contain only full-squares, not those cropped squares at the border. Maybe the algorithm misinterprets them as distorted full-squares and tries to undistort them.

Comment: @Micka Yes, the chess board is completely visible, it is from the OpenCV's standard stereo image sets(see [left](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/left01.jpg) and [right](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/right01.jpg) image), The posted image is the output of rectification process which is weird!

Comment: The cropped squares at the border should not be a problem. This is what I get with the [calibration.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.1.0/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp) sample for left images. It should be possible to do the same with the stereo calibration sample.

Comment: `image_width: 640
image_height: 480
board_width: 9
board_height: 6
square_size: 1.
aspectRatio: 1.
flags: 2
camera_matrix: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 5.3590117051349637e+02, 0., 3.4227429926016583e+02, 0.,
       5.3590117051349637e+02, 2.3557560607943688e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
distortion_coefficients: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 5
   cols: 1
   dt: d
   data: [ -2.6643160989580222e-01, -3.8505305722612772e-02,
       1.7844280073183410e-03, -2.7702634246810361e-04,
       2.3850218962079497e-01 ]
avg_reprojection_error: 3.9229331915929899e-01`

Comment: I don't have problem with the calibration, the rectification causes the headache!!

Comment: Just to make sure for people that might encounter that question in the future : almost all OpenCV features have example code in the "Sample" document of the source repository. For your case, in python, [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/calibrate.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find what was the thing I did wrong which led to incorrect answers, but for what it worth I have found a solution that does rectify OK and more!!
I came across the [StereoVision](https://github.com/erget/StereoVision) library and considering the low documentation level it has, I have managed to fetch/write the following snaps which calibrate and rectifies OK.

```
import cv2
import os.path
import numpy as np
from stereovision.calibration import StereoCalibrator, StereoCalibration
from stereovision.blockmatchers import StereoBM, StereoSGBM

calib_dir = 'data/config/calibration'
if(not os.path.exists(calib_dir)):
    calibrator = StereoCalibrator(9, 6, 2, (480, 640))
    for idx in range(1, 14):
        calibrator.add_corners((cv2.imread('images/left%02d.jpg' %idx), cv2.imread('images/right%02d.jpg' %idx)))

    calibration = calibrator.calibrate_cameras()
    print "Calibation error:", calibrator.check_calibration(calibration)
    calibration.export(calib_dir)

calibration = StereoCalibration(input_folder=calib_dir)

if True:
    block_matcher = StereoBM()
else:
    block_matcher = StereoSGBM()

for idx in range(1, 14):
    image_pair = (cv2.imread('images/left%02d.jpg' %idx), cv2.imread('images/right%02d.jpg' %idx))
    rectified_pair = calibration.rectify(image_pair)
    disparity = block_matcher.get_disparity(rectified_pair)
    norm_coeff = 255 / disparity.max()
    cv2.imshow('Disparity %02d' %idx, disparity * norm_coeff / 255)

    for line in range(0, int(rectified_pair[0].shape[0] / 20)):
        rectified_pair[0][line * 20, :] = (0, 0, 255)
        rectified_pair[1][line * 20, :] = (0, 0, 255)

    cv2.imshow('Rect %02d' %idx, np.hstack(rectified_pair))
    cv2.waitKey()
```

The following is the result of rectification of the same image I have posted in my question.
[image]
Although for computing the disparity map It needs its parameters to be tuned(a tool is provided by the package) but it will do the job :)

Comment: did u ever find a better solution for this? I am having the same problem @dariush

Comment: @KaranJoisher I guess I did, but I don't recall what was it!